# JavaDoc annotations

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I have created a small java project with maven. The javadoc is included in the `pom.xml` as needed.

But when I use the generated jar file in another project, the comments made using annotation such as `@param` and others are missing. When

> Add unimplemented methods (from eclipse)

, the parameters are named `agr0, arg1, etc.`.. and not `usersame`, `password`.

I don't know how it should be done to get the javadoc documentation right when using an IDE such as Eclipse or IntelliJ

I did add the javadoc plugin as follows:

```
<plugin>

            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>

            <executions>
                <!-- JavaDoc Plugin to generate a JAR containing documentation from 
                    the project. -->
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
           </executions>
</plugin>
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it doesn't matter which IDE you use if javadoc have been included you should see it when hovering the documented class/method or field. My guess is that you have not included it, you could use [`maven-javadoc-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/usage.html) add it to your pom.

Comment: ok you are creating a jar for javadoc as I see here so to import your javadoc in your eclipse see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289617/eclipse-how-to-link-a-jar-containing-javadocs-source-with-its-binary